# Is it possible to implement Laravel pagination on a custom foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have set of Ids as an array. It is out put of a complex search logic. For example my array is :

```
array(2,5,1,8,9,12,83,32);
```

Each of these IDs are valid and represents posts. So what I do is I just loop them in a for each loop and collect all data to a final array. Example :

```
foreach($ArrayOfIds as $id)
{
$posts[] = Post::findOrFail($id);
}
```

then I send this $posts to my view. Is it possible to implement laravel pagination in this scenario.? Keep in mind that I can't play any more with $ArrayOfIds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, example using `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

```
public function showPost()
{
    $posts = [];
    foreach($ArrayOfIds as $id) {
        $posts[] = Post::findOrFail($id);
    }

    $perPage = 6;
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($posts, count($posts), $perPage);
    $items = $paginator->getCollection();

    return $paginator->setCollection(
        $items->forPage($paginator->currentPage(), $perPage)
    );
}
```

At first, I instantiate `LengthAwarePaginator` class and feed it with the arguments needed, [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L41). And then, as I need to set which posts belongs to which page, I then use `forPage` method from [`Illuminate/Support/Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L662).

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clean reply. What if showPost() function responds in JSON ?

Comment: Never mind. I figured out. Thanks a lot for the help.